# How can I use Linq with JSON to get all the Ids from this odd JSON?

Tags: c#, json, linq

I receive JSON from a web service that looks something like this:

```
{
   "RESULTS": {
      "1220": {
           "DDR_TYPE_ID": 7,
           "DDR_ID": 5199,
           "DDR_NAME": "Mesa Building"
      },
      "5455": {
           "DDR_TYPE_ID": 7,
           "DDR_ID": 417,
           "DDR_NAME": "Scottsdale Building"
      },
      "1462": {
           "DDR_TYPE_ID": 12,
           "DDR_ID": 3324,
           "DDR_NAME": "Gentry Building"
      }
   }
}
```

I can't really serialize in my usual method because this isn't an array of the same objects thanks the the strange numbered keys.

All I need from this is a list of the `DDR_ID` values.

Is there a way to use Linq to JSON to get these values from this JSON?  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *"strange numbered keys"* (or any other dynamic keys) can be taken care of by deserializing to a dictionary. So, for example, if you had a class like this:

```
public class MyJSON
{
    public Dictionary<int,ResultItem> Results { get; set; }
}

public class ResultItem
{
    public int DDR_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then, after deserializing you should be able to get your id's with something like:

```
var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyJSON>(jsonString);   // using JSON.Net
var ids = myObj.Results.Select(p => p.Value.DDR_ID);
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2FpjeC)

Answer (score 2):

If you want avoid using other objects:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var jObject = JObject.Parse(json)["RESULTS"]; 
var result = jObject.Select(x => x.First["DDR_ID"]).Values<int>();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to use Linq to JSON to get these values from this
>   JSON?

Using Linq to JSON you can get the values like this with no need for other objects

```
var obj = (JObject) JObject.Parse(json)["RESULTS"];
var ids = obj.Properties().Select(p => (int)p.Value["DDR_ID"]);
```